# Как вызвать функцию, которая определена в actions, внутри window.addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

В компоненте в `methods` есть функция, внутри которой с помощью `window.addEventListener` отслеживается скролл страницы. Если в `window.addEventListener` обратиться к `this.$store.dispatch('somFunction')` возникает ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined".

Как вызвать функцию, которая находится в `actions`?

Comment: Специально перепроверил, все работает. Никаких ошибок, не должно быть. Проверьте свой store там есть `export default` и есть ли доступ к этому actions из других мест.

Comment: Из других мест все работает нормально. В methods  есть функция которая обращается к actions, она срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, вы устанавливаете обработчик события на отслеживания скролла страницы как-то так:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
   this.$store.dispatch('somFunction')
})
```

Если так, то `this` в данном случае указывает на объект `Window`. В этом можно убедиться, если залогировать `this`

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
   console.log(this)
})
```

Так как в объекте `window` не содержится свойства `$store`, то `window.$store` вернет `undefined`. Отсюда вы получаете ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Вам нужен `this`, который указывает на экземпляр vue-компонента. Для этого вам можно сохранить ссылку на экземпляр vue-компонента в переменную

```
var vm = this
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
   vm.$store.dispatch('somFunction')
})
```

Или использовать стрелочную функцию. [Внутри функций-стрелок – тот же this, что и снаружи](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#funktsii-strelki-ne-imeyut-svoego-this)

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
   this.$store.dispatch('somFunction')
})
```

Comment: Автор вопроса, перечитай ответ, возможно почитай доки про контекст js, и пометь данный ответ как решение